# mysqli_connect: Prevent 127.0.0.1 from changing to "localhost"

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

My host is blocking "localhost", so I have to use 127.0.0.1 instead. When I try to run the connection php script, I get this error "Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". Is there a php function to keep the IP address instead of "localhost"?

Comment: In your database connection routine, you just specify `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is already specified there. `$sql_con = mysqli_connect($sql_server, $sql_username, $sql_password, $sql_db);` and `$sql_server = "127.0.0.1";`

Comment: `127.0.0.1` wouldn't get reverse resolved to `localhost` I think. So, the problem probably is somewhere in your script

Comment: I also tried this script on XAMPP and it works fine there. It's just the problem that it does not keep the IP when running the script. My hosting company told me they're blocking "localhost" for security reasons and I have to use the IP 127.0.0.1

Comment: Can you acess data with http://localost through browser?

Comment: You should ask your server admin for db host name

Comment: Got it. I used " instead of ' and the password contains a $. It took me 5 hours to recognize this -.- Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This message commonly means that the username/password is wrong.

Also try to use 127.0.0.2 instead of 127.0.0.1

*I can't understand how blocking localhost but allowing 127.0.0.1 could increase security..*

Comment: 127.0.0.2 gives me this error: `Host '127.0.0.2' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.`. This hosting company is strange in many ways... :D

Comment: so "Access denied" error means that you **connected to a mysql server, but mysql server itself refused connection**. I hope you double-checked password?

Comment: I checked both username and password several times and asked the hosting company if the password is really the right one...

Comment: Got it. I used " instead of ' and the password contains a $. It took me 5 hours to recognize this -.- Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Disabling hostname lookup in mysqld is one of the steps in improving its performance. The trade off is that accounts using a hostname instead of ip wont work anymore. Im running into this issue myself. The only solution seems enabling lookup again in mysql.